# Is a NAT Gateway needed when configuring an AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, nat

I have configured the `API Gateway` with a `lambda` function. The `lambda` function is in a VPC with private subnets. I have also attached an internet gateway to the VPC with a route table routing all traffic to the internet gateway. From what I understand, I still shouldn't be able to access any of the API endpoints, as the lambda function is in a private subnet and needs a NAT gateway between the internet gateway and private subnets.

However, with the security group assigned to the `lambda` function allowing incoming traffic, I am able to access all endpoints.

Comment: What are the "API endpoints" that you mention? Are you referring to the ability to connect to AWS services such as Amazon S3? Also, you say that the VPC contains only private subnets, but attaching an Internet Gateway and updating the Route Table to use it will turn these subnets into Public subnets. Or were these _different_ subnets that the one(s) where the Lambda function is attached? The Inbound rules for on a Security Group will _not_ be used by the Lambda function, since it does not receive requests via the network, or were you referring to Outbound rules?

Comment: You only need a NAT Gateway if the Lambda function needs to make API calls out of the VPC, like to access something on the Internet. NAT Gateways are for outbound connections, they are not used at all for inbound connections. Also, inbound rules on a Lambda function's security group are meaningless, they are not used at all, since Lambda functions don't accept inbound network requests at all, API Gateway accepts the inbound network request, and then invokes a Lambda function with the request data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Gateways are used for Inbound communication, whereas NAT Gateway is used for outbound communication.

Hence for inbound traffic, once you configure the API Gateway routing to lambda, with appropriate security policy, you can access the api.

For outbound communication, your Private service needs to access NAT gateway which will route traffic to Internet gateway and further out to the internet.